# How to set ImageView's size same as image and make it centered?

Tags: android, xml, image, android-layout, imageview

As you can see, I have a frame layout and inside of it, I have an `ImageView`. When I use code below and set an image to `ImageView`, image does not appear at the center of screen, and frame and `ImageView` does no wrap the image. In other words some white blanks appeared out of image in `FrameLayout`. All I want to do, make `FrameLayout` and image view's sizes same as image and make them centered at the screen.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/editor_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What are you drawing in `ImageView`?

Comment: what is parent layout of FrameLayout ?

Answer (score 0):

To center the image in the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/editor_frame"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Center horizontal and vertical has to be true in `FrameLayout`, then it will be in center of your parent layout, also do it with `ImageView`. It will draw in center of `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/editor_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but when I add a view to frame layout  , layout changes. However I solved my problem, so I don't need what I asked.

Comment: @harunurhan it should change because it is `wrap_content`. If you do not want it to change make it fixed size like `android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp"`. Anyway, glad you made it :)